# Django using bulk_update to update all records

Tags: django, django-models

With 2.2 we now have the option to bulk update:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

I have a model with say millions of rows and I want to efficiently update all the records. I am trying to use bulk_update, but which means I still have to load all the model objects in the memory, modify the field one by one and then use bulk update:

What I am doing:

```
def migrate_event_ip_to_property(apps, schema_editor):
    Event = apps.get_model('app' 'Event')
    events = Event.objects.all()

    for event in events:
        if event.ip:
            event.properties["$ip"] = event.ip

    Event.objects.bulk_update(events, ['properties'], 10000)
```

Since there are millions of records, can I avoid doing Event.objects.all() and load all objects into the memory even while using bulk_update?

Comment: What is `event.properties`? You could run the bulk update on every 1000th iteration for example and use `iterator()` so that you don't load them all at once

Comment: Also, how do you ensure that the order of objects is preserved in each iteration if you run it in batch?  Also iterator does not save memory, generator does.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iterator

Comment: A generator is an iterator btw

Comment: What about restricting the fields you load in memory with `Event.objects.all().values('id','properties')`

Comment: @IainShelvington can you post the sapmle code? I am not sure how do you ensure the same ordering of the queryset results when done in batches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def migrate_event_ip_to_property(apps, schema_editor):
    Event = apps.get_model('app' 'Event')
    chunk = []
    # Use iterator to save memory
    for i, event in enumerate(Event.objects.only('properties', 'ip').iterator(chunk_size=10000)):
        if event.ip:
            event.properties['$ip'] = event.ip
            chunk.append(event)
        # Every 10000 events run bulk_update
        if i % 10000 == 0 and chunk:
            Event.objects.bulk_update(chunk, ['properties'])
            chunk = []
    if chunk:
        Event.objects.bulk_update(chunk, ['properties'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory is your main concern, what about restricting the fields you load in memory with :

```
Event.objects.all().values('id','properties')
```